# Looping through characters in String

Tags: c, string, for-loop, if-statement, conceptual

I'm looping through each character in this string inputted by the user. The string only consists of 'o' 'g' and 'c'. So for each character, I want to make a certain symbol print to the screen.

I think I can do this by using if statements inside the loop but I'm a little confused on what goes inside the for loop: The following is real and pseudo code idk what goes inside the pseudo-code yet, thus, this question:

So, the first string is inputted by user: say occccgggooo.
here's the function I'm working on:

```js
     void printSymbol(char *str)
     {
       int i;
       counter = 0;
       for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
       { //pseudo code begins
         if(o in string)
             printf("/*some symbol*/");
             counter++; //How do i incorporate a counter to move to next character?
         if(g in string)
         .......
```

And so on. I just don't know what goes inside each if statement to recognize each character in the string.

Also, maybe instead of repeating each if statement I can create some function to call instead? should it just be if (str[i] = 'o') and so on? then have a counter variable move the loop forward?

Comment: Yes, you are correct it will be `str[i] == 'o'`, this way you are checking that the ith character equals 'o'

Comment: How would I incorporate a counter variable into the for loop? I would use it to move on to the next character int the array.

Comment: The `i` variable is the counter here, incrementing `i` is then taking you to the next element of the array.

Comment: Awesome, I just realized that actually I should have tested that before asking, thanks

Comment: "sudo code begins" --> "[pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) begins"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the strings are null-terminated('\0') char arrays,
You are using '/0' which is not valid.
Try the below code:

you can use `s[i]` to access a character at `ith` index.

```js
 void printSymbol(char *str)
 {
   int i;
   counter = 0;
   for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
   { //sudo code begins
     if(s[i]=='o')
         printf("/*some symbol*/");
        //How do i incorporate a counter to move to next character?
        // No need to use a separate counter, `i` will be incremented in the for loop.
     if(s[i]=='g')
     .......
```

Comment: Ah, that was a typo

Comment: Okay, you can access the characters with s[i], I will be incremented in the for loop.